# Github Shared Storage

Tags: git, github, vps

So I have a weird problem here.
I'm doing some web development, and using Github to track changes.
I have my IDE setup to automatically update my web-facing VPS with code changes, as the website isn't critical, more just a fun way for me to practice programming.

However, I have a friend who is working on the project with me. If he want to work on the site, they need access to all the server resources (MySQL servers etc.), so I can't just have them work on a local copy and then push commits.

> Is there any way to give them access to the server, and be able to make edits, and then commit those, or will doing things this way totally screw up the repo when I later try to to pull the current version but my files have already been updated.
>
> Would it be much better to have him edit locally and just access the MySQL server remotely? Then he can push his edits to the current branch, and I can pull them so they get synced with the server?

Sorry for the pretty convoluted question, I'm new to working with Git and with web development.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with codeWizard's edit. Having the server accessed by any of the team member's working on the project should be done remotely as the content type stored in the database with mySQL should stay consistent especially considering if you're using it in relation to content management system like WordPress/Drupal/Joomla. Editing code together via Github has been my way of managing code from my desktop and my laptop on the go.

This is the same set up that I use when I edit code away from home.

Comment: Soo... Are you thinking he should just run his own copy of the server, and then link it to the main mySQL server? The main alternatives are that or just having him edit the server files directly.